# AWS DynamoDB - save a JSON Array to a table (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How do you save a JSON Array as an item attribute? AWS documentation is the absolute worst thing ever - it contradicts itself, a lot of things are either redundant or only partially explained, some things aren't explained at all - I don't know how anyone manages to use it.

Anyway, suppose I have a table called Paths, and a path has a name, an ID, and a list of LatLngs (formatted as a JSON Array)

In the class definition for this table, I have

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Paths")
public class Path {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private JSONArray outlineJSON;
```

with getters and setters like

```
@DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

which works fine for strings, booleans and numbers, and the object saves successfully to the table.
AWS documentation mentions JSON several times, and says it can handle lists, but it doesn't explain how to use lists or give any examples.
I used @DynamoDBHashKey for the id, @DynamoDBRangeKey for name, and @DynamoDBAttribute for other strings, numbers or booleans, and I tried it here

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "outline")
private JSONArray getOutlineJSON() {
    return outlineJSON;
}

private void setOutlineJSON(JSONArray outlineJSON) {
    this.outlineJSON = outlineJSON;
}
```

It successfully saved the object but without the array.

How do I save the array? I can't find an explanation anywhere. I think @DynamoDBDocument might have something to do with it, but all the documentation on the subject gives unrelated examples, and I can't find any using a list like my in situation.

**EDIT**: For now, I have a working solution - I can easily convert my lists to JSONArrays and then convert those to Strings, and vice-versa.

Comment: I may have made some progress - I've gathered from some examples similar to this that I might be able to define a custom object class with the DynamoDBDocument annotation at the beginning and just save an attribute that is a List of these objects... not working yet but I think this is closer to the answer...

Comment: are you using aws sdk for java or aws sdk for android?

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference, since Android is Java. That is definitely not clear in the AWS documentation...
I assume Android? Is it not obvious from my sample code?
If it helps, I'm using the dynamodb mapper to save and scan tables, but like I said that only works for string, number, and boolean attributes

Comment: AWS has SDK for Java and Android, both are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your class to be something like

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Paths")
public class Path {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private LatLang latLangs;

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
  public String getId() { return id;}
  public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}

  @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "name")
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

  @DynamoDBDocument
  public static class LatLang{
       public String lat;
       public String lang;
  }
}
```

Comment: So then should I have an attribute that's a List or JSONArray of instances of this custom class (LatLng)?

Comment: You could also have a hashmap if you don't want to have a class